# Why is $\langle f, u \rangle_{H^{-1}, H^1} = (f,u)_{L^2}$ when $f\in L^2 \cap H^1$ and not $\langle f, u \rangle_{H^{-1}, H^1}=(f,u)_{H^1}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

More generally, if $V \subset H \subset V'$ are Hilbert spaces, why is $$\langle f, u \rangle_{V',V} = (f,u)_{H}$$ when $f\in H \cap V$ and not $$\langle f, u \rangle_{V',V}=(f,u)_{V}?$$

Is this what people mean when they say that

> $V$ is not identified with its dual
>   ?

What is $\langle f, u \rangle$ mean precisely in terms of the embeddings when $f \in L^2?$

Comment: As Haim Brezis writes in his book on Functional Analysis, you can either identify $V$ and $V^*$ *or* $H$ and $H^*$. But not both.

Comment: @Siminore But whether $V$ is part of Hilbert triple or not it certainly has a Riesz representation in $V$ inner product. So the notation needs explanation; it's not a natural deduction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the source of confusion is the concealment of the embeddings and of the Riesz isomorphism in $H$.

Let us denote by $E : V \to H$ the (bounded and linear) embedding and by $R : H' \to H$ the Riesz map of $H$. Then, the embedding from $V$ to $H'$ is given by $R^{-1} \, E$ and from $V$ into $V'$ it is given by $E^* \, R^{-1} \, E$ (this is different from the Riesz map in $V$!).

Then, for $v \in V$ and $f \in V$, you have
$$
\langle E^* \, R^{-1} \, E \, f , v \rangle_{V',V}
=
\langle R^{-1} \, E \, f , E \, v \rangle_{H',H}
=
( E \, f, E \, v)_H.
$$
Now, removing again the $E$'s and $R$'s you clearly see that
$$
\langle f , v \rangle_{V',V}
=
(f, v)_H.
$$

Comment: So when we write $\langle f, v \rangle$ where $ f \in H$ we actually mean to write $\langle E^* R^{-1} E f, v \rangle$, but we don't because it's messy. Strange how no PDE book ever mentions this.

Comment: For $f \in H$, $v \in V$, $\langle f, v\rangle$ actually means $\langle E^* \, R^{-1} \, f, v \rangle$ (no $E$ needed here - the $E$ is needed for $f \in V$. For me, the strangest confusion was that conditions like $\frac{\mathrm d v}{\mathrm d t} \in L^2(0,T;V')$ actually depend on $H$ in a hidden way.