# weak derivative of a vector valued function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Consider $T>0$ and $U$ a opensubset of $R^n$ ,bounded  and with smooth boundary. Consider ${\Omega}_T = U \times (0,T]$. Let $u: {\Omega}_T \rightarrow R $ a smooth function.

Define $h : [0,T] \rightarrow H^{1}_0 (U)$ given by $h(t) = u(. ,t)$ . 
What is the weak derivative  of $h$ ?. I believe that is the function $ v : [0,T] \rightarrow H^{1}_0 (U)$ given by $v(t) = u_t (.,t)$. am I right ?

Someone can give me a hint to prove or disprove  ?

I think this is the answer because   $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{h(t+h) - h(t)}{h} = u_t (.,t) $. Then I believe that in this abstract context the classical derivative will be the weak derivative (as in Sobolev spaces ) .

For the definition of weak derivative see : [about weak derivative of Bochner integrable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424909/about-weak-derivative-of-bochner-integrable-function)
thanks in advance.

Comment: You can verify the definition directly; it is just integration by parts.

Comment: @NateEldredge do you know some book with the integration by parts formula for the bochner integral ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to find $g:[0,T]\to H_0^1(U)$ such that $$\tag{1}\int_0^Th(t)\varphi'(t)dt=-\int_0^T g(t)\varphi(t)dt,\ \forall\ \varphi\in C_0^\infty(0,T)$$

Fix $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(0,T)$. Note

\begin{eqnarray}
 \int_0^T h(t)\varphi'(t)dt &=& \int_0^T u(\cdot,t)\varphi'(t)dt      \nonumber \\
   &=&- \int_0^T\frac{\partial u(\cdot,t)}{\partial t}\varphi(t)dt \\
\end{eqnarray}

How to justify the integration by parts in Bochner Integral? Try find out what is $$\int_0^T (u(\cdot,t)\varphi(t))'dt$$

Comment: Hi @Tomás , Thank you ! you are very good !  I am searching this "basic" properties of the weak derivative in this abstract context. About you asked to me I find nothing ... I found some good lectures and books, but they dont talk about what you asked me. For your  question I believe in this : $\int_{0}^{T}(u(.,t) \varphi(t))^{'} \ dt= \int_{0}^{T} \frac{\partial u(.,t)}{\partial} \ dt + \int_{0}^{T} u(.,t) {\varphi}^{'}(t) \ dt$. am I right ? Do you have a favorite a book about bochner integrals and weak derivatives in this abstract context?