# $C_0^\infty(0,T)\cdot V$ dense in the Bochner space $L^2(0,T;V)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $V$ be a Banach space and $(0,T)$ a time interval. Consider the space $C_0^\infty(0,T)$ of infinitely often differentiable functions with values in $\mathbb R$ and compact support in $(0,T)$ and the space $L^2(0,T;V)$ of square [Bochner integrable functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space).

It holds that $C_0^\infty(0,T)$ is dense in $L^2(0,T;\mathbb R)$, see, e.g., Cor. 4.23 in [Brezi's book](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Brezis&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=Books&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=2759829)  on Sobolev Spaces and PDEs .

Does a related result hold in the Bochner space setting, namely, is

$$
C_0^\infty(0,T)\cdot V := \left \{ f_v\in \bigl((0,T)\to V \bigr) :\quad f_v=\phi v, \quad v \in V,\quad \phi \in C_0^\infty(0,T)\right \} 
$$
dense in $L^2(0,T;V)$?

Comment: I know it's a bit late but you might want to check the book of Ben Schweizer "Partielle Differentialgleichungen". In Addition there is a nice pde script of John Hunter: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf where also Bochner integrals are introduced

Answer (score 1):

No. First you should observe that $C_0^\infty(0,T) \cdot V$ is not a subspace. For two (not colinear) vectors $v_1, v_2$, the function $f(t) = \chi_{(0,1/2)}(t) \, v_1 + \chi_{(1/2,1)}(t) \, v_2$ is cannot be approximated.

The set of all finite linear combinations of functions from $C_0^\infty(0,T) \cdot V$ is dense in $L^2(0,T; V)$.

Comment: Yes, true. Fortunately, the linear hull of $C_0^\infty(0,T)\cdot V$ is still OK for my purposes. Do you know a reference to the latter claim?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to prove that the definitions of weak derivatives $\dot v \in L^2(0,T;V')$ of $v\in L^2(0,T;V)$ in the weak sense and in the 'pointwise' sense via $\langle \dot v(\cdot), w \rangle \colon (0,T) \to \mathbb R$, for all $w\in V$, are equivalent. Cf. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424909/about-weak-derivative-of-bochner-integrable-function/425353#425353)

Comment: No, I do not know a reference. However, it should be easy to prove by using an argument involving mollifiers.